# How can I monitor a Smart-UPS 2200 in PRTG?

Tags: monitoring, ups, physical-environment

This UPS is connected via a serial cable to a server. I am trying to get the temperature readings off of the sensor that is connected to the UPS and get them in PRTG. We were able to do this in the past and then when we changed the server out, we lost the settings. Does anyone have any info that might help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Install Powerchute business edition, make sure SNMP service is installed on the server and then monitor via SNMP.

I found that the correct OID is: 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.2.2.2.0

Jim